# What are the country-specific cryptocurrency prices on Yahoo finance?

Tags: exchanges

I was under the impression that cryptocurrency prices were set by an exchange's currency volume and buy/sell averages, so what exchanges are used to get the Yahoo finance data with country-specific cryptocurrency prices?

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in the footer under the details for BTC-AUD: `Data provided by CryptoCompare`

On this page: https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-AUD?p=BTC-AUD

Comment: Right, but CryptoCompare lists the prices for a number of different exchanges, whereas Amazon lists prices for a currency by country, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TQM I suppose Yahoo Finance just makes use of the compiled data provided by CryptoCompare.I suppose there is nothing much more exciting to find out. On this [page](https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/overview) there is a drop box to choose what currency. It makes sense that Yahoo Finance can just be pulling live data.